# How would I get strtok() to return the decimal number and not whole numbers?

Tags: c, matrix, decimal, strtok

I have a function that reads in a file and prints it out as a grid.

This is the file (input):

```
2 2
1.83 5.64
7.36 4.10
```

But when it prints out the matrix it only returns whole numbers (output):

```
2 2
    1.00     5.00 
    7.00     4.00
```

How do I get the function to print out the decimal number?

Wanted Output (i.e):

```
2 2
    1.83     5.64 
    7.36     4.10
```

Comment: "I have a function that reads in a file and prints" --> post that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't `strtok`, it's this:

```
double newVal = strtol(value, &ptr, 10);
```

`strtol` converts the string to a `long`, not a `double`, so it's discarding the fractional portion.  Use `strtod` instead:

```
double newVal = strtod( value, &ptr );
```